# Is there a way to know when GC overhead limit is exceeded?

Tags: java, error-handling

I have a 2D array that reaches GC overhead limit when inside a for-loop, is there a way to have an if-statement that when the GC error occurs, it stops the for-loop without returning the error to the console? And at the same time, my 2D array would reach it's maximum.

Comment: That would be the wrong approach. You need to write your code (which you're not showing) so it doesn't cause an error.

Comment: the reason the error is occuring is because the 2D array is a table with rows and columns, there are 9 columns by 1000000 rows. I would like to stop the array at it's maximum before exiting with an error.

Comment: Why do you want that? What are you going to do with a half-initialized array?

Comment: I would return it as a table and show a graphical error to the user that the maximum has been reached and a table with maximum number of rows has been returned.

Comment: But you're not reaching a maximum. You're creating too much garbage for the GC to handle. You want to fix your code so it doesn't create too much garbage. Then you'll only have to worry about running out of memory.

Comment: it's just an exception (`OutOfMemoryException` I think) you could catch.